# Case statement with array includes?

Tags: ruby, array

What is the best practice to implement case checks using arrays in Ruby?

```
def partition(a)
  a_values = [1,4,5]
  b_values = [2,3,7]

  a.group_by do |n|
    case n
    when *a_values then :a
    when *b_values then :b
    else :c
    end
  end
end

partition((1..10))
#=> {:a=>[1, 4, 5], :b=>[2, 3, 7], :c=>[6, 8, 9, 10]}
```

The example uses the splat operator * to check against given arrays. I"m in doubt about the performance impact. What do you suggest?

Comment: What exactly is your use case? Where do `a_values` and `b_values` come from, and do they always contain three values each? Please read [ask], and add contextual information to clarify the question. Also retitle the question to state the task that is accomplished by the code, rather than your concern about `case` statements.

Comment: There should no contraints about the array values. In my contrete case, the arrays contain 2 or 3 value of integers which represent states of an entity/model.

Comment: I was faced with problem several times in other projects with different arrays. Therefore I asked the question in this abstract way, sorry.

Comment: It's hard to give you good advice based on abstract or hypothetical code. I recommend posting an excerpt of code from a real project.

Comment: @200_success I don't see the issue. In my real project I use constants to give the integer values of  `a_values`, `b_values` a meaning. The array `a` from the example is an array of `ActiveRecord` models and the `case` statement considers a field `status` of the model. Does these details add valuable information?

Comment: Yes, context matters. Please post real code.

Comment: I second the recommendation to edit the title, maybe something like "Separating an array by custom groupings"

Answer (score 2):

I would consider using a `case` statement with no variable. Something like:

```
case
when a_values.include(n) then :a
when b_values.include(n) then :b
else :c
end
```

you could do the same using `if` if there are only two options.

If there were a lot of arrays I would do something like:

```
VALUES = {
  a: [1,4,5],
  b: [2,3,7],
  ... 
} 
result,_  = VALUES.find( ->{:c} ){ |key,array| array.include(n) }
```

or possibly inverting that:

```
# If the values are contiguous:
VALUES = [nil, :a, :b, :a, :b, ... ]
# If the values are *not* contiguous:
VALUES = { 1 => :a, 2 => :b, 3 => :a, ... }
result = VALUES[n] || :c
```

If you are concerned about performance the I would suggest comparing the performance with a more straight-forward implementation using `if`. A constant is also likely to perform better than defining the arrays each time the method is called.

Answer (score 0):

**Review**

Overall, I don't see anything wrong stylistically. I wouldn't be too concerned about performance unless you have extremely large arrays -- do you expect either the values "buckets" or the input array to be huge? If so, you have justification to be concerned but be careful not to prematurely optimize.

I recommend changing the name of the method. There is already a `partition` in Enumerable, and it works kinda like a `group_by` except it divides an array into exactly two parts. Using that name for this method which does something different may be a bit confusing.

**Alternative implementation**

So this uses Marc Rohloff's idea and just fleshes it out:

```
def bucketize(arr)
  a = [1,4,5].map{|n| [n,:a]}.to_h
  b = [2,3,7].map{|n| [n,:b]}.to_h
  values = a.merge(b)

  arr.group_by { |n| values[n] || :c }
end
```

It precomputes a hash-based lookup table. I suspect that this will be slower for small arrays, but faster for large ones.